# How to prevent PhoneGap camera plugin to sync automatically with cloud?

Tags: android, cordova, android-camera, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using MobileFirst 6.3.0.00-20141218-1823 and I have used PhoneGap camera plugin to take pictures and store the same with its metadata in the local storage.

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(successFunction, failureFunction, {
        quality : 50,
        sourceType : navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
        destinationType : navigator.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        targetWidth: 640,
        correctOrientation : true,
        targetHeight: 480
    });
```

My phone is in sync with a cloud. I could notice that the pictures taken using this plugin are uploaded in the cloud immediately. How do I prevent such auto sync of pictures taken using PhoneGap camera plugin to the cloud?

Answer (score 0):

That's got nothing to do with MFP nor Cordova.
Cordova is not who is syncing to cloud - that's the Android OS's doing.

There is also no such specific method or mention in the Cordova Camera API either, that I could find: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/doc/index.md

This is an individual setting (disable/enable cloud syncing from the photo gallery, where photos are stored after being taken) that every end-user may choose on his/her own. IMO it is not under your responsibility nor right to tell the end-user what to do with a photo that s/he took.